# omit template parameter (for function pointer argument)

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, pointer-to-member, function-signature

I'm writing template factory that stores function pointer to create user objects.
I would like to support user Creation function with and without argument (for now, one or zero argument will do). 
(and i can't use boost or c11 unfortunately )

```
template< typename T, typename K, typename D >
//T (Type) is a polymorphic type
//K (Key) should have operator < and be copyable
//D (Data argument for creator function) can be copyable
class Factory
{
public:
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<T> shared_ptr;
    //auto gen Ctor and Dtor

    inline void Add( const K& key_, T* (*CreatorFunc)(D) );
    inline shared_ptr Create(const K& key_, const D& initData_ ) const;

private:
    std::map<K, T* (*)(D) > m_creator;
};
```

I would love it if the user can use it like this:

```
class c1
{
public:
    explicit c1(const string& st);
    ...
};

class c2
{
public:
    explicit c2();
    ...
};

c1* CreateC1(const string& st){ return new c1(st);}
c2* CreateC2(){ return new c2;}

...
//Factory<type, key, arguments>
Factory<c1, int, string> f;
f.Add(0, CreateC1);
f.Create(0, "string Arg");

//Factory<type, key>
Factory<c2, int> f2;
f2.Add(0, CreateC2);
f2.Create(0);
```

i did manage to get this to work with some ugly template specialization. i feel like i'm going at it the wrong way.

my solution:

```
class EmptyClass {};
template< typename T, typename K, typename D = EmptyClass>
class Factory
{
public:
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<T> shared_ptr;

    inline void Add( const K& key_, T* (*CreatorFunc)(D) );
    inline shared_ptr Create(const K& key_, const D& initData_ ) const;

private:
    std::map<K, T* (*)(D) > m_creator;
};

template<>
template< typename T, typename K >
class Factory<T, K, EmptyClass >
{
public:
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<T> shared_ptr;

    inline void Add( const K& key_, T* (*CreatorFunc)() );
    inline shared_ptr Create(const K& key_) const;
private:
    std::map<K, T* (*)() > m_creator;
};
```

feel free to criticize anything else if you wany

Answer (score 0):

If you can use variadic template maybe this would work for you:

```
template< typename R, typename K, typename...Args>
class Factory
{
    using func_ptr = R*(*)(const Args & ...);
    using return_ptr = std::shared_ptr<R>;

public:
    inline void Add(const K& key_, func_ptr value);
    inline return_ptr Create(const K& key_, Args... initData_) const;

private:
    std::map<K, func_ptr> m_creator;
};
```

A possible implementation might look like this:

```
template< typename R, typename K, typename...Args>
class Factory
{
    using func_ptr = R*(*)(const Args & ...);
    using return_ptr = std::shared_ptr<R>;

public:
    inline void Add(const K& key_, func_ptr value)
    {
        if (value != nullptr)
        {
            m_creator[key_] = value;
        }
    }

    inline return_ptr Create(const K& key_, Args... initData_) const 
    {
        auto iter = m_creator.find(key_);
        if (iter == m_creator.end())
        {
            return return_ptr(nullptr);
        }
        return return_ptr(iter->second(initData_...));
    }

private:
    std::map<K, func_ptr> m_creator;
};
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe you could write a base class for the map and the `Add` function and your typedefs. I don't see a way of simplifying the `Create` function.